# how to compare user input data with my firestore record

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to compare the input data of a user, with my firestore record (data that is already stored in my Firebase.

```
Task<QuerySnapshot> pLJava = CoRef
            .whereEqualTo("ProgrammingLanguages", "Java")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            // document.getData();
                            id = document.getId();
                            if (id.contains("Java")) {

                            }
```

I already wrote an algorithm to query the input data. Now I want to compare the input data with my Firebase record.

Thanks for all the help in forward!

Comment: Please ask your question explicitly. What is your problem? What did you try already and failed?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply convert the document into a POJO. There's a method `toObject(Class<T> valueType)` in Firestore API which resolves that.

```
YourClass foo = document.toObject(YourClass.class);
```

Then, you may compare the object data with the user's input data.

Comment: Very good idea, I'm trying to implement it in my code i'll let you know soon if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Massin_NYC You're welcome. Let me know if you have resolved your problem. :)

Comment: I converted the document into an object. Now I want to compare the input of the object. Should I use the Hash function for this?

Comment: @Massin_NYC No. Write a function, which takes as an argument your object. Then, inside the function, compare the fields of the object with your input data (only those fields which do matter for you).