# flutter firestore where query is not working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app i need to compare my user input data with firestore datas using where query. but its not displaying anything.

here is my code

```
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> comparision(BuildContext context) async* {
        yield* Firestore.instance.collection('Schedules')
            .where('from', isEqualTo: widget.from)
            .where('to', isEqualTo: widget.to)
            .snapshots();
      }
```

and the Stream builder

```
    StreamBuilder(
          stream: comparision(context),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData){
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  DocumentSnapshot power = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                  return Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(power['from']),
                        Text(power['to'])
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
            );
          },
        )
```

when i remove the where query it displays everything.

Firestore structure is below(NB: here only the field 'from' is shown, but there is a field named 'to' as well)

[Firestore structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjLa4.jpg)

how can i fix this?

Comment: To look into this for you, can you provide a screenshot of your Firestore data structure?

Comment: i included the structure... https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjLa4.jpg this is the image link

Comment: I've found a document here that can help you narrow down the problem. (https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/)

Comment: still it doesn't explain for not displaying with global variable

Comment: I need clarification please. Can you please tell me about the global variable? Can you show me more code with the global variable?

Comment: it is a booking app and the user selects from a dropdown that stored on `from` & `to` variables and pass that to the 2nd screen. then i use that variable in `widget.from` & `widget.to` form and compare if that data exists in firestore

Comment: To offer better advice, can you explain what you mean by not displaying with global variable?

Comment: @MrTech i initialize a variable `from` & `to` in first page and pass them on to second page. this variables has a value of dropdown. after reaching the second page it will display the values with a text widget. but when I try to use it in `where` query it doesn't return any value nor it has an error.

Comment: I was able to find this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61588740/how-to-compare-user-input-data-with-my-firestore-record). Please look if it helps.

Comment: The link describes how to interact Firestore with Flutter, comparing data.

Comment: @MrTech it's still not working tho. do you want me to upload all my source code?